# Make script in Unity to Unreal

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Im new to Unreal. I tried to follow the tutorial into making A* pathfinding:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhiFx28e7JY&t=1252s&ab_channel=SebastianLague

I don't really know how to change the script made in Unity to Unreal.

UnityScript

```
public class Node {
    
    public bool walkable;
    public Vector3 worldPosition;
    
    public Node(bool _walkable, Vector3 _worldPos) {
        walkable = _walkable;
        worldPosition = _worldPos;
    }
}
```

My UnrealScript:

```
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct FAS_Node
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category= "Nodes")
    FVector worldPosition;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category= "Nodes")
    bool walkable;

    Node(bool _walkable, FVector _worldPos){
        walkable = _walkable;
        worldPosition = _worldPos;
    }
};
```

it return error saying Node doesnt have return type

Comment: It seems like a typo, `Node` should be `FAS_Node`.

Comment: doing that it said this error below:
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.26\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Public\UObject/Class.h(1173) : error C2512: 'FAS_Node::FAS_Node': no appropriate default constructor available

but if i return void it do allow it to compile

Comment: In UE4 every `USTRUCT` requires a default constructor, so you need to add one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you cannot create constructors with parameters in such way in UE4. Try define a default constructor.
If you really need to pass parameters to it - check ObjectInitializer constructor here: https://ikrima.dev/ue4guide/engine-programming/uobjects/new-uobject-allocation-flow/